# Is there a non-constant $h \in \mathbb{C}[x_1 , \dots , x_n ]$ that divides every element of this given ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $I ⊆ \mathbb{C}[x_1 , \dots , x_n ]$ be an ideal with the property that any two
>   elements $f_1$ , $f_2 \in I$ have a non-trivial common divisor. Then there is a non-constant $h$ which divides every element of $I$.

I tried to use the fact that $\mathbb{C}[x_1 , \dots , x_n ]$ is a Noetherian ring to do induction on the number of generators of $I$. But I did not succeed.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hint: there exists an element $g\in I$ of least degree.

Comment: Using your hint I can conclude that given any other $f \in I$, the common divisor of $f$ and $g$ is not in $I$. But I don't know how to proceed. Any other hint?

Comment: @LeonardoSchultz: that's not quite the right conclusion. It fails, for example, for principal ideals, which do have the property given in the problem. Do you see how to correct the conclusion?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. The correct conclusion would be: If $h$ is the common divisor of $f$ and $g$, then $h=g$ or $h \notin I$. Right?

Comment: Yes—but since we are told that $h\in I$, the other possibility $h=g$ is the only possibility.

Comment: @GregMartin Why $h∈I$ ? The problem only says that if  $f,g∈I$, there is a non-trivial common divisor, it doesn't say that this common divisor must lies in $I$.